# Listen for editor commands in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am building an extension for VS Code. My extension will show the key bindings associated to a recently action (I am a fan of this for helping me learn key bindings).

Looking through the documentation there seems to be a way to access the [commands in the editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#_commands), but no way that I can find to listen for actions / commands as they are invoked.

Is this possible with the current API? Or should I create a feature request in Github?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible with the current release 0.10.3. I opened an [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1431) in Github and was told by one of the devs that its not possible right now. It is a feature request for future versions. If it becomes available I'll update it here.